# Getting error "Cannot find name Cashfree" while using cashfree payment integration in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cashfree

Migrating to 2022-09-01 Cashfree
documentation link : https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/checkout-migration-to-version-2022-09-01

Added the js sdk script in `index.html` in the public folder

```
<script src="https://sdk.cashfree.com/js/ui/2.0.0/cashfree.sandbox.js"></script>
```

But while doing

```
let cf = new Cashfree(session_id)
getting error "Cannot find name Cashfree"
```

How to import or use `"new Cashfree()"` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add the javascript SDK url in the index.html which is in the public folder, try importing it by adding

```js
let cf = new window.Cashfree(session_id)
```

wherever required

Comment: It worked , actually I was using it in typescript thats why it gave error , so used this with "//@ts-ignore" and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

We can use NPM package of cashfree to get over this problem.
For the sandbox environment we can use
`import { cashfreeSandbox } from "cashfree-pg-sdk-javascript";`

Furthere details are provided in below link.
[Implementation of cashfree redirection through cashfree-pg-sdk-javascript](https://socket.dev/npm/package/cashfree-pg-sdk-javascript)